# Sort multiple parts of an object array with in javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking for an efficient solution to the following problem:

[image]

Basically, need to put items with status pending at the top and every other status below, then sort each section by name in alphabetic order.

My current solution looks like this:

```
sort(data){
  const pending = [];
  const nonPending = [];
  data.forEach((item) => {
     if(item.status === 'Pending') { //case insensitive logic can be added
        pending.push(item)
     } else {
        nonPending.push(item);
     }
  });

  pending.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });

  nonPending.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });

  return pending.concat(nonPending);
}
```

Comment: Why not use a standard sort with a custom function that handles both fields?

Comment: More general sort operation: // Sorting function
const customSort = (a, b) => {
  // First, sort by status
  if (a.status < b.status) return -1;
  if (a.status > b.status) return 1;

  // If status is the same, sort by name
  return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
};

// Apply the custom sort to your array
const sortedRows = rows.sort(customSort);

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check the status up-front, while sorting.

```js
const things = [
  { id: 1, name: "A", role: "User", status: "" },
  { id: 2, name: "C", role: "Admin", status: "" },
  { id: 3, name: "D", role: "Supervisior", status: "Pending" },
  { id: 4, name: "B", role: "", status: "" },
  { id: 5, name: "J", role: "Admin", status: "" },
  { id: 6, name: "K", role: "", status: "" },
  { id: 7, name: "L", role: "something", status: "Pending" },
]

const sorted = sort(things);

sorted.map(record => console.log(JSON.stringify(record)));

function sort(data) {
  return data.toSorted((a, b) => {
    // Float a, if pending
    if (a.status === 'Pending' && b.status !== 'Pending') return -1;
    // Sink a, if b is pending
    if (a.status !== 'Pending' && b.status === 'Pending') return 1;
    // Normal name comparison
    return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

**Note:** Since names are not unique, you should also consider sorting by ID or role.

```js
return a.name.localeCompare(b.name) || // Compare name first
       a.role.localeCompare(b.role) || // Then role
       a.id - b.id;                    // Finally, ID
```

Comment: Solution looks really good! Curious to how it works, edge cases particularly instances where it fails. Sorting by name is a requirement however, role can be used as a tie-breaker.